# Configuring nginx with ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm having trouble configuring ssl with nginx; I followed the instructions [here](https://ssl.comodo.com/support/certificate-installation--nginx.php) step by step (without step 4) but it didn't work and i got error 524 from cloudflare.

This is my configuration file for nginx located in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name     <domainname>.org;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/<domainname>_org/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/<domainname>_org/<domainname>_org.key;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location /static {
                alias <path/to/static>;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass      <python/listener>;
                include         /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect  off;
        }
}
```

Note that if i changed the configuration to:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name     <domainname>.org;

        ...
}
```

then I can reach the server normally with http and every thing will be working fine.

**Note**
I already opened the port in the firewall so that's not the problem and nginx is listening on port 443 when i check using netstat.

Comment: Did you checked the nginx access log.

Comment: perhaps you need to recompile nginx with ssl support

Comment: @Jijo I checked it now, I got something strange, when i configure nginx with http, it works fine but when i change the configuration to https, i see new IP, and the request is not '/' it is something else i don't know where it came from, even the user agent changes

Comment: @Aurangzeb I installed nginx directly, i didn't compile it, so i think it should support ssl